# How to make 2D array from 1D array of char string in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, 2d

This is code, I've got after making similar function where string are integers, but something is wrong when I change int with char

int main()

{
char A[ ] = "RRTTYYHH";

```
int len = 8;

char B[2][4];   

int i;

int j;

int k = 0;

int row = 2;

int column = 4;

for (i = 0; A[i] < row; i++)

{
    printf("\n"); 
    
    if(k == len) 
   
     break; 
    
    for (j = 0; A[j] < column; j++)
   
    {
        B[i][j] = A[k]; 
        
        printf("%s\t", B[i][j]);

        k++; 
    
    }

 }

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In the for loops, change the A[i] to i and A[j] to j to iterate correctly over rows and columns.

In the printf, you can use %c instead of %s, as the chars in the 2D version won't be null terminated (like strings or %s expect).

Example:

```
int main()
{
    char A[] = "RRTTYYHH";
    
    int rows = 2, columns = 4;

    char B[rows][columns];

    int k = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            B[i][j] = A[k];
            
            printf("%c\t", B[i][j]);
    
            k++;
        }
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In printf you can use %c instead of %s

```
int main()
{
    char A[] = "RRTTYYHH";
    int len = 8;
    char B[2][4];
    int k = 0,i=0,j=0;
    int rows = 2,cols = 4;
    while(i<rows)
    {printf("\n");
       j=0;
       while(j<cols)
       {
            B[i][j] = A[k];
            printf("%c\t", B[i][j]);
            j++;
            k++;
       }
        i++;
     }
    return 0;
}
```